# Automatically generate circuits on its own in PLECS (Piece-wise Linear Electrical Circuit Simulation )

Tags: matlab, vectorization, simulink

Is there any way I could program the Matlab/Simulink to be able to automatically generate circuits on its own? I am using PLECS blockset (Piece-wise Linear Electrical Circuit Simulation ) embedded in Simulink.

For example, I need to have hundreds of identical block in a single .mdl file, instead of inserting one by one by myself by calling the block which I previously saved in Simulink library, is it possible that Simulink can be programmed to automatically generate hundreds of blocks by itself?

The only way I was told is by "using vectorization for most components. Most components are vectorized if they have a vectorized input signal or if one of their parameter is specified as a vector." However, I could not find any further information/details, appreciate if anyone of you could give opinion on this?

I just want to know if this is possible? Else, I would have to try another approach?

Thanks!

edited on 10 July 2013: Further to my question, I have confirmed with Plexim that there isn't such features ( add_block and add_line) in Plecs (Piece-wise Linear Electrical Circuit Simulation), does anyone know if there is any way I could automate the Plecs model? Appreciate any suggestion...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use functions like [`add_block`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/add_block.html) and [`add_line`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/add_line.html) to automate the creation of your Simulink model from a library.

Comment: Thanks am304 for giving me the direction, I find a very useful link reproduced here, in case anyone is looking for the same solution... http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2010/01/21/building-models-with-matlab-code/

Comment: Further to my question, I have confirmed with Plexim that there isn't such features ( add_block and add_line) in Plecs (Piece-wise Linear Electrical Circuit Simulation), does anyone know if there is any way I could automate the Plecs model? Appreciate any suggestion...Thanks

Comment: `add_block` and `add_line` work work with standard Simulink block and from looking at the Plecs documentation (I have no experience of it), it looks like it should work with the blocks from `plecslib` as long as the library path is referenced correctly. However, I'm not sure if components that go within a "circuit" blocks will work. It's probably more a question for Plecs rather than MATLAB/Simulink.